# How to Hide Server/Software Version from Apache Zeppelin/Any Related Web-App?

Tags: apache-zeppelin, penetration-testing

Any ideas/suggestions on how to hide software/server version from Apache Zeppelin? We hired an information security company to perform an external pen-testing in our servers and one of the issues raised was to hide all the software versions being disclosed on application headers/errors messages.

So for example if I execute this command from a terminal:

```
curl -I -k https://localhost:8181/
```

It will give this result

`HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Thu, 16 Jul 2020 03:37:42 GMT Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE Date: Thursday, July 16, 2020 1:37:42 PM AEST Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Content-Type Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, HEAD, DELETE Date: Thursday, July 16, 2020 1:37:42 PM AEST Content-Type: text/html Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Jun 2017 09:18:50 GMT Accept-Ranges: bytes Content-Length: 3657 Server: Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210)`

How can I hide the `Server: Jetty(9.2.15.v20160210)` or is it even possible? I'm trying to search but no luck yet on finding a solution for this. Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance! Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible in the Zeppelin 0.9.0 (not yet released) - it's implemented as part of the [ZEPPELIN-4586](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-4586) and should be available in the 0.9.0-preview2 soon, or you can compile from source yourself.  You can look to the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/master/docs/setup/security/http_security_headers.md) in the meantime

Comment: Thanks mate! Super appreciate your help. I was able to hide the server & software version after cloning Zeppelin-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT and self compiling it. Cheers.